# libGDX Android logcat classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I saw that this is a common problem, but still couldn't find the solution and so I decided to ask you guys for some help.
I wanted to run the Android luncher of my libGDX project on my device, but for some reason it always crash, which in the past didn't happen.
This is what I got in the logcat:

```
12-16 23:10:28.343: D/AndroidRuntime(2531): Shutting down VM
12-16 23:10:28.343: W/dalvikvm(2531): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41902ac8)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.game.dogs.android/com.game.dogs.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.game.dogs.AndroidLauncher" on path: /data/app/com.game.dogs.android-1.apk
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2131)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:146)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.game.dogs.AndroidLauncher" on path: /data/app/com.game.dogs.android-1.apk
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
12-16 23:10:28.343: E/AndroidRuntime(2531):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: are you using android studio?

Comment: No. I am using Eclipse.

Comment: I'd try using Android Studio, because the gradle integration is better. `1.0` came out the other day too.

Comment: Since I'm used to and therefore more comfortable with Eclipse, I hope there is another solution.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your java build path - your class is not making it onto the device. Create an empty project with the Libgdx setup jar, import it into eclipse, and compare its build path with yours.

Comment: To import into my current workspace or a new one? In a new one it worked fine and I'm using the same SDK if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Compare your package name in AndroidManifest.xml and package of your Launchers

Comment: It actually worked when I wrote in the xml android:name=".AndroidLauncher"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the following class:

```
com.game.dogs.AndroidLauncher
```

But the class is in the subpackage ".android":

```
com.game.dogs.android.AndroidLauncher
```